# how to writing junit test for opengl es2.0 android app

Tags: android, junit, opengl-es, mockito, opengl-es-2.0

i was new to this android testing. What i want is to write a junit(with Mockito) test for my fragment which is a GLSurfaceView with one Custom GLRenderer.

```
public class SuefaceViewFragment extends Fragment{

private View mRootView;

private GLSurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private CustomRenderer mRenderer;


public SurfaceViewFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_surface_view, container, false);
    initView();
    return mRootView;
}


private void initView() {
    mSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

    mSurfaceView .setRenderer(mRenderer);
    mSurfaceView .setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);        
    mSurfaceView .setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSurfaceView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSurfaceView.onPause();
}
```

}

this is the GLSurfaceView

```
public class CustomRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {




public CustomRenderer() {

}



private void init() {

    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    init();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    render();
}

private void render() {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   // To Do Rendering code

}
```

I want to write unit testing for this above fragment using using Junit and Mockito. is it possible? if possible how to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unit tests test your business logic. they specifically do not work with anything involving the android sdk (include fragments)

Testing GLSurfaceView is not possible by any of the android test frameworks. UiAutomator and Espresso both need a view to test on (a button to click for example) and the reason why open gl is so fast is partly because it doesn't belong in a view tree. the only "view" android knows about is the GLSurfaceView.

You *might* be able to just record touch events and replay them via adb send touch events to interact with the app. it will work, but it is brittle.